# HTTP Callout after async DML

Tags: apex, mixed-dml, calloutexception

I'm trying to do HTTP callout after DML in future method, but I'm getting `System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out`.

What I'm missing? Is it possible? Test code is below.

```
public with sharing class UncommittedTest {
  public static void main() {
    dmlAsync();
    callout();
  }

  public static void callout() {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
    System.debug(':::callout: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
  }

  @future
  public static void dmlAsync() {
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account ' + DateTime.now());
    insert acc;
    System.debug(':::async dml: ' + acc.Id);
  }
}

// Test in execute anonymous: UncommittedTest.main();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending)

Comment: no, that one does callout in a future method, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make DML in future method and then issue callout

Comment: It is not possible, below is nice explanation (still not official) why -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301291/why-salesforce-doesnt-allow-us-to-do-call-out-after-a-dml-operation-what-they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for a future transaction is a transaction which needs to be inserted into an object after which it will get called asynchronously. This DML is what is preventing you from making the callout.

You can instead fire an platform event with type `Publish immediately` not `publish after commit` and it will work.

Comment: Great, that's what I'm doing right now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform a callout after any modification to the database, including calling future methods. The solution is to make the callout asynchronous instead:

```
public with sharing class UncommittedTest {
  public static void main() {
    doDml();
    callout();
  }

  @future
  public static void callout() {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://www.google.com');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
    System.debug(':::callout: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
  }

  public static void doDml() {
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account ' + DateTime.now());
    insert acc;
    System.debug(':::async dml: ' + acc.Id);
  }
}
```

If, for some reason, the DML and callout must both be asynchronous, you'll need to use Queueable instead.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can fire and forget DML in future method and continue with my callout, but docs are only mentioning future method for callouts, that's why I was confused.